# For a pandas Series, shouldn't s.sort_index(inplace=True) change s?

Tags: python, pandas

Given this code:

```
s = pd.Series([1,2,3], index=['C','B','A'])
s.sort_index(inplace=True)
```

Shouldn't `s` now look like this:

```
A    3
B    2
C    1
dtype: int64
```

When I run this, `s` remains unchanged. Maybe I'm confused about what the `inplace` argument is supposed to do. I thought that it was supposed to change the  Series on which the method is called.

For the record, this does return the sorted series, but it does so whether or not you set `inplace` to True.

Answer (score 9):

You are indeed correct with your expectation. However, this was not yet implemented before 0.17 / a bug in 0.17 that this keyword was ignored instead of raising an error (like before). But a fix will be released in the upcoming version 0.17.1.

See https://github.com/pydata/pandas/pull/11422

So for now, easiest is just to use it without `inplace`:

```
In [4]: s = s.sort_index()

In [5]: s
Out[5]:
A    3
B    2
C    1
dtype: int64
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to have a dataframe:

```
s = pd.DataFrame([1,2,3], index=['C','B','A'])

s.sort_index(inplace=True)

s
Out[25]: 
   0
A  3
B  2
C  1
```

`inplace` for [`sort_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.17.0/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sort_index.html) works on DataFrame, not series. For series you have to redefine it.

Comment: `sort_index` *also* works for a Series, just not the `inplace` keyword.

Comment: sort_index works on both DataFrame and Series. Starting from version 0.17 inplace keyword is supported.

Comment: @shanmuga not in 0.17.0, which is what I have, `inplace` does not work. I was meaning about `inplace` when I said it works on DataFrame, that's why I said *For series you have to redefine it*